# Add product title heading tag for WooCommerce category archive pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, html-heading

I'm looking to change heading tag for products displaying on product category page (from no heading tag to H2) but **only on product category page**.

I found 2 solutions, which work, however they also change heading tag for products displayed on other pages, which I don't want.

**1. By changing heading tag in content-product.php file**

It works, however that also changes products displayed in related products on a product page.

```
<div class="box-text <?php echo flatsome_product_box_text_class(); ?>">
    <?php
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );

        echo '<h2 class="title-wrapper" style="font-size: 100%">';
        do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );
        echo '</h2>';
```

**2. By adding code in functions.php file for woocommerce-loop-product**

It works, but it changes heading tag everywhere, even for products displayed on the home page.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'soChangeProductsTitle', 10 );
function soChangeProductsTitle() {
    echo '<h2 class="' . esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_loop_title_classes', 'woocommerce-loop-product__title' ) ) . '">' . get_the_title() . '</h2>';
}
```

Maybe the first solution is the best and I just need then to add code in related.php file or in funtions.php file, for changes on heading tag don't apply on related products?

I never learned to code, I'm blocked here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the conditional tag `is_product_category()`as follow:

**1. By changing heading tag in content-product.php file**

```html
<div class="box-text <?php echo flatsome_product_box_text_class(); ?>">
<?php
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
    
    if( is_product_category() ) { 
        echo '<h2 class="title-wrapper" style="font-size: 100%">';
    }

    do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );

    if( is_product_category() ) {
         echo '</h2>';
    }
```

**2. Or by adding code in functions.php file arround `woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title` hook**

```php
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'product_heading_title_on_category_archives', 1 );
function product_heading_title_on_category_archives() {
    if( is_product_category() ) { 
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );
        add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'change_product_heading_title', 10 );
    }
}
function change_product_heading_title() {
    echo '<h2 class="' . esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_loop_title_classes', 'woocommerce-loop-product__title' ) ) . '">' . get_the_title() . '</h2>';
}
```